# Input signal out of range?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, monitor

Whenever I try to run a 3D app, I get this error, and I can't do anything; I have a  NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nForce 430 graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

From what i know that means the resolution used by the application  is not supported by your monitor, try to change the resolution of the app or force it to run in window mode